# If I install MySQL-python using pip, does that means that I can use MySQL server/client?

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL-python using pip.

Does that mean Mysql has also been installed in my system?

If than, how can i access it through terminal command?

Comment: "I have installed MySQL-python." how? "Does that mean Mysql has also been installed in my system?" depends on the "how". "If than, how can i access it through terminal command?" again, how you installed it?

Comment: @Braiam I decided to post on U+L for once and who do I see? :D

Comment: @Braiam.....I have installed MySQL-python using pip.

Comment: Edit your question and include that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Depends on how you installed MySQL-python. If with "pip" no.
- If MySQL was installed you would have had to supply a user and password. I doubt you would forget either. Easiest method to check if MySQL is installed you will have a `/etc/mysql/` directory.
- You can check the process list to check if MySQL is running with `ps -ef | grep mysql`. If it shows no processes it is not running.
- Connecting from command line to MySQL is done with ...

  ```
  mysql
  ```

  or if you have a user ...

  ```
  mysql -u {user} -p
  ```

  and it will ask for the user and password used to set MySQL up.

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work, that's why i have asked the question. Thanks, i have got my answer.

Comment: Mysql is running, but i am having an error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: @ni8mr If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will signify to everyone that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site. **If you have new additional questions, ask that question in a new post possible linking to this one as background info**